# Coloring items partially in a list

Tags: color, enumitem

I see the way to make all numbered items in a list a single color. But I need to selectively choose which item should be colored. For example I would like the first and second items numbers to be in color, but not the third.

Answer (score 1):

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\def\reditem{\item[\color{red} \addtocounter{enumi}{1}\arabic{enumi}.]}
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\reditem foo 
\reditem foo 
\item foo

\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Of course, in a nested list you *cannot* use this custom item but other with the `enumii` counter, and so on.

Comment: It may be good to note that these `\reditem`s can't be `\ref`erenced if they're `\label`ed. (This may or may not be relevant for the intended use-case.)

Answer (score 1):

To address the comment of @Circumscribe here a version where the regular `\item` command is used to allow referencing.

The color is set using the `label` option for `\begin{enumerate}` provided by the `enumitem` package. This option is normally expanded before the items are processed, so each item would be printed in the color that was set at the start of the list, however by using `\noexpand` this expansion is delayed until the actual processing of the items.

For referencing `enumitem` provides another option `ref` that controls the appearance of the reference, in the MWE below this is without a specified color and without the dot.

To make setting the color easier I defined a small extra command `\setcl` that (re)defines the `\itemcolor` command.

Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\def\setcl#1{\def\itemcolor{#1}}
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=\color{\noexpand\itemcolor}\arabic*.,ref=\arabic*]
\setcl{red}
\item foo
\item foo\label{second}
\setcl{black}
\item foo
\end{enumerate}
We are interested in item \ref{second}.
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

With a syntax in which you specify what items to color:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem,xcolor}

\newenvironment{emphenumerate}[1][red!90!green]
 {%
  \colorlet{emphenumerate}{#1}%
  \enumerate[label=\protect\maybecoloritem\arabic*.,ref=\arabic*]
 }
 {\endenumerate}

\newcommand{\maybecoloritem}{\ifcoloritem\color{emphenumerate}\fi\global\coloritemfalse}
\newcommand{\emphitem}{\global\coloritemtrue\item}
\newif\ifcoloritem

\begin{document}

\begin{emphenumerate}
\emphitem First
\emphitem Second
\item Third
\end{emphenumerate}

\begin{emphenumerate}[.]
\emphitem First
\emphitem Second
\item Third
\end{emphenumerate}

\end{document}
```

Only first level is provided, but you can improve it with `enumitem` facilities.

You can change the color with an optional argument to `\begin{emphenumerate}`; in the example I show how to remove the coloring, but you can use any `xcolor` specification of a defined color.

[image]

Avoid pure colors, they're too vivid.

Comment: Just curious: why did you make the assignment of `\ifcoloritem` global? I'm having difficulty coming up with a situation where it matters.

Comment: @Circumscribe Well, if you remove `\global` you get red also the last item

Comment: Oh, I see! I was looking at the `\global` in `\emphitem`, but it's the `\global` in `\maybecoloritem` that matters. Nice.